# A master trigger

Tags: sql, oracle11g, auditing

friends, I need your help,
I have a problem, I need to create a trigger that stores in a table all the interaction (access, insert, update, etc) that runs with the database; that saves who(user), when and what did (the query that was executed) in oracle.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You gave very few information on what you actually need, but you seem to be looking for the `AUDIT` functionality, that is available in Oracle 11g (that you tagged your question with).

From the docs :

> Auditing is the monitoring and recording of selected user database actions. In standard auditing, you use initialization parameters and the AUDIT and NOAUDIT SQL statements to audit SQL statements, privileges, and schema objects, and network and multitier activities.

Check out [this documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10575/tdpsg_auditing.htm#TDPSG50000), or [this other one](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10575/tdpsg_auditing.htm#TDPSG50000)